# Controlling the names of integration variables in DSolve

Tags: core-language, variable

Consider the following command

```
DSolve[{Derivative[2][y][x] == g[x]}, y[x], x, 
  GeneratedParameters -> (Subscript[C, #] &)]
```

With the following result

[image]

How can I control the name of the variables `K[1]` and `K[2]` which appear as the integration variables?

As you should note I was able to change the variable names `C[1]` and `C[2]` with the `GeneratedParameters` option.

I noticed this issue since I used the variable `K` somewhere before `DSolve` command in my code and the result of `DSolve` became messy! So I am inclined to change the dummy variables names before the `DSolve` starts solving.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: I am not sure there is direct way to control the dummy variable names; but you can post-process the output to rename `K[i]` ,e.g., `DSolve[{Derivative[2][y][x] == g[x]}, y[x], x, 
  GeneratedParameters -> (Subscript[C, #] &)] /. 
 K[i_] :> Subscript[K, i]`

Comment: @kglr: Thanks for the attention. :) I noticed this issue since I used the variable `K` somewhere before `DSolve` command in my code and the result of `DSolve` became messy! So I am inclined to change it before the `DSolve` starts solving. :)

Comment: @H.R. Your comment is an illustration of the common knowledge about MMA: don't use upper case names for user defined variables - all built-in MMA functions are upper case, and specifically `K` is a built-in symbol. Btw, note that `Subscript[C, 1]` is not a new symbol: it's an expression with `Subscript` as a `Head`, and `C` (a built-in symbol) is still present in the code and can cause harm in your future computations.

Comment: @corey979: Thanks :) I knew about the things you said. In fact, I usually use the `Notation` package and `Symbolize` command to prevent the issues you mentioned but I have not faced such an issue like this before! :) I cannot stop my self using capital letters! :D Maybe I should change my mind.

Comment: You can define `K[n_]:= Subscript[\[FormalX],n]` at the beginning of your notebook.

Comment: @chuy I don't think so, if `K` is already defined "somewhere before `DSolve` command in my code...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
K = 42;
Block[{K}, 
  DSolve[{Derivative[2][y][x] == g[x]}, y[x], x, 
    GeneratedParameters -> (Subscript[C, #] &)] /. 
  K[i_] :> Subscript[\[FormalCapitalK], i]]
```

[image: result]

Comment: (+1) So just using delayed rule was the solution? :) Many Thanks. :)

Comment: @H.R. No, that was just habit on my part. It works with `->`.  The solution was to use `Block` and to do the replacement inside the block, which prevents the top-level evaluator from replacing `K` with 42.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice the Block! Thanks again